# Python: How to use pretty printing with Sympy?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formula, sympy, pretty-print

I'm working on a little Python project in VScode, and I am using Sympy to work with some formulas. But for some reason, I simply can not figure out how to use pretty printing with Sympy. I tried reading the documentation but I'm still stuck. Im not sure if this makes any difference, but i dont have a front-end yet, so everything is printed to the terminal.

**Any ideas on how to use pretty printing with Sympy in VScode?**

Comment: Have you called `sympy.init_printing()`?

Comment: Yes I have called `sympy.init_printing()` after importing all the things @Talon

Comment: Hard to know from the description what exactly isn't working because you don't say what the results are. Another possibility is to use the `sympy.pprint` function.